# How do I find out what code is causing JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run `yarn start` but get this:

> Starting the development server...
>
> ts-loader: Using typescript@3.9.10 and C:\DevTools\git\mymoto\tsconfig.json
>
> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [9076:000001F4910F0DA0]   120343 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2045.0 (2051.8) -> 2044.3 (2053.0) MB, 1410.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.123, current mu = 0.011) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
> [9076:000001F4910F0DA0]   122662 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2045.4 (2052.0) -> 2044.6 (2053.0) MB, 2288.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.057, current mu = 0.013) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
> 1: 00007FF79BA7021F napi_wrap+109311
> 2: 00007FF79BA15286 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+33302
> 3: 00007FF79BA16056 node::OnFatalError+294
> 4: 00007FF79C2E054E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
> 5: 00007FF79C2C53CD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
> 6: 00007FF79C16F85C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
> 7: 00007FF79C17AB9A v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
> 8: 00007FF79C177D49 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
> 9: 00007FF79C16C971 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
> 10: 00007FF79C16AB75 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1317
> 11: 00007FF79C18AF67 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+183
> 12: 00007FF79BEBAFF1 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1409
> 13: 00007FF79C368EFD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+463949
> 14: 000001177FAE26D4

I've seen a few questions on here they all seem to suggest something along the lines of `node --max_old_space_size=8048`. In most cases the question has highlighted the code which causes this. I can't figure out what this is. How do I find out what is causing the issue? I'd like to initially see if there's anything wrong there rather than blindly trying something.

Could having a copy of my `node_modules` folder in the project folder cause this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my `node_modules` folder and also a `node_modules_backup`. When I deleted `node_modules_backup` the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue a while back. This helped me

```
 node --max-old-space-size=8048
```

Have you tried using NVM? Downgrading your Node/Typescript version can help you. I used Node v14.15.5 btw.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'm on v14.15.1.

Comment: Excellent, let me know how that goes

Comment: That didn't resolve my issue but I tried restarting my laptop. Problem solved. Unfortunately I use Windows in work.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this problem for myself.

Followed all of the comments on [this Vite issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2433) and nothing worked. However, when I did a deep analysis of my dependencies with `npx depcheck`, I saw that there were a ton of dependencies I had installed that I was not using in my repo. I cleared them out, deleted node_modules, and re-ran `npm i`.

Then I reran the build command (with the memory increase command) and thankfully fixed the problem. This took me all day to fix, hoping to relieve this sore spot for someone else.

As I am using Vite, this is the exact `npm run build` command I ran to get it working: `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=15872 && tsc && vite build`